# How is connection performance for Azure VMs with Sql Server with 1433 endpoint in load balanced set?

Tags: sql-server, azure, virtual-machine, load-balancing

This [article explains how to use Azure Internal Load Balancer to load balance SQL Servers in virtual machines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-internal-getstarted/).

Since SQL server connections are stateful, how would this load balancing affect connection pooling and performance regarding connections?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my article:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/improving-the-quality-of-sql-server-database-connections-in-the-cloud/

Basically use connection pooling but make sure you also use connection reiliency.

If you need high performance locate your app near the database, SQL server traffic over the Internet isn't great whereas http is better (if it is a web app).

For 100% if you use azure over the Internet do no have MultipleActiveResultSets=true in connection string as it will slow down any request or response over 4 packets.

Any load balancer works the same in regards to SQL, if you have a connection to SQL and are running something and the connection goes down (either the server stops or the connection drops for whatever reason) you will need to create a new connection and re-issue the command. The connection resiliency stuff helps - *but* the problem you will find is that it takes a while to detect a dropped connection (you need to use it to see if it is broken) - you need to test your app with different levels of dropped packets (use a wan emulator) to see how it behaves.

As I said test but if you are looking for a good trade off between connections not being dropped / re-connecting as quick as possible / using connection pooling to stop the TDS session setup (around 1 second / new connection latency depending) then have a smaller pool and set your connection timeout quite low (~5 seconds rather than the default 15 seconds).

Long term tcp connections over the internet are pretty unreliable, AWS used to have a thing (don't know if they still do) where they would drop any idle tcp connection after 5 minutes (this went down to about 30 seconds when I was monitoring during the royal wedding in the uk when traffic went crazy) - *note* that this is annecdotal from my experience.

Ed

Comment: Thanks for the info @Ed Elliot. It didn't really answer how the Azure internal load balancer works with a stateful connection, but gave more information towards an informed decision.

Comment: cool, sorry - I have expanded it to include some info about the load balancer